reledmac: \Xlinenumannotationonlyfirst does not seem work
New to this forum (and relatively new to reledmac); I am having a stubborn issue. I cannot seem to get \Xlinenumannotationonlyfirst to work. It continues to print the line numbers for lemmas on the same line. I must be missing something. Can you lend a hand?
My MWE:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{reledmac}
    \Xlinenumannotationonlyfirst[A]
    \Xlinenumannotationonlyfirstintwo[A]

\newcommand{\witness}{\textbf}

\begin{document}

\beginnumbering
\pstart

\edtext{Hieronimus}{\lemma{Hieronimus}\Afootnote{Ieronimus \witness{P2}}} ait: Nisi matrimonium fuisset, 
\edtext{uirginitas}{\lemma{uirginitas}\Afootnote{et uirginitas \witness{P1} \witness{P2} \witness{P3}}} non esset: ex matrimonio terra 
\edtext{impletur,}{\lemma{impletur,}\Afootnote{\emph{om.} \witness{I} \witness{M4}}} ex 
\edtext{uirginitate}{\lemma{uirginitate}\Afootnote{uirgitate \witness{W1} \witness{B} \witness{M1} \witness{W3} \witness{Wu}}} 
 caelum. \\

\pend
\endnumbering

\end{document}

Thanks!

Welcome to the forum!
Unless your MWE is leaving something out, you are not using any line number annotations, therefore \Xlinenumannotationonlyfirst is idle. Maybe you are looking to suppress the line number? Then the commands would be \Xnumberonlyfirstinline[A]and \Xnumberonlyfirstintwolines[A].

Off topic, you don't need the \\ to make a new line and in fact, it is best to stick to reledmac's own commands and make a new \pstart (with \noindent if needed). reledmac also responds nicely to \linebreak if you need to break a too-long line organically (i.e. keep it justified).

If I understand your question correctly, you would like to suppress a line number, not a line number annotation.
And since your MWE doesn't contain any line number annotations, \Xlinenumannotationonlyfirst is trivially idle.
To suppress the line number under the desired conditions, use the commands \Xnumberonlyfirstinline[A] and \Xnumberonlyfirstintwolines[A]
(§ 7.4.1 of the documentation).
Off topic, you don't need the \\ to create a new line and in fact, it is best to stick to reledmac's own commands and make a new \pstart (with \noindent if needed).
reledmac also responds nicely to \linebreak if you need to manually break a too-long line organically (i.e. keep it justified). Personally, this happens to me when the edition text contains complicated math formulas that fail to break.
